# Error after upgrading MongoDB Node.js driver to 3.7.4 in Jest tests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs, node-modules, ts-jest

I recently upgraded my MongoDB Node.js driver to version 3.7.4, and my Jest tests are now failing. The error seems to be related to the "require-at" module. Specifically, the problem occurs when the code tries to execute **`Fs.statSync(xdir)`** where **`xdir`** represents the path to my project root. In this context, **`Fs.statSync(xdir)`** is returning **`undefined`**.

Interestingly, when I run the same command in the Node.js terminal with the same version and permissions, it returns a valid object. This leads me to believe that there might be something specific to how Jest or my test environment is handling file system operations.

```
const Fs = require('fs');
const xdir = '/path/to/my/project/root';

try {
    const stat = Fs.statSync(xdir);
    console.log(stat); // Outputs 'undefined' in Jest tests, but valid object in Node.js terminal
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

**Additional Context:**

- I am using Jest for running my tests.
- I have recently upgraded my MongoDB Node.js driver to version 3.7.4 (previous version was 3.6.4).
- The issue occurs specifically when running tests with Jest.
- The code works fine in the Node.js terminal using the same version of Node.js and the same permissions.

**Steps I've Taken:**

1. Checked the file paths to ensure they are correct.
2. Verified file system permissions for the specified path.
3. Tried running the code outside of Jest tests (in a regular Node.js script) and it worked as expected.
4. Reverted back to the previous version of the MongoDB Node.js driver (where the tests were passing) and the issue disappeared.

I'm not sure what might be causing this discrepancy between Jest tests and regular Node.js execution. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.